# adding new syscall to freebsd using kld

Tags: freebsd

in order to add a new syscall to free bsd, i've added a syscall.c at user/share/examples/kld/syscall/module and I have compiled it using "make".but now I'm confused! I've no idea what to do next!
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do "kldload ./syscall.ko", from that directory.

Comment: thanks! and just one more question! how can we call that syscall?!

Comment: Take a look at share/examples/kld/syscall/test/.

Otherwise, you would want to extend sys/kern/syscalls.master, then do "make sysent", and then rebuild world, which would automatically generate the libc part of the syscall.  But for the way used in the example above, the "call.c" way of doing it is enough.